# Error using md-grid-list on smaller screen size

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am building a mobile website that displays a grid-list of products.

In order to implement the grid list I am making use of `md-grid-list` directive of angular material.

This is the part of my code that implements the above functionality:

```
<div id="products-row" infinite-scroll="fetchNextPage(nextCategory,1)" infinite-scroll-disabled="busy">
    <md-grid-list md-cols-gt-md="3" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-sm="1" md-gutter="5px" md-row-height="2:1">
         <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="p in productsOfCurrentCat">
             <product data="p" id="product-item"></product>
         </md-grid-tile>
        <div ng-show="busy">Loading more products....</div>
    </md-grid-list>
</div>
```

This works quite well on larger screen size. When I view the webpage on a smaller screen size using the toggle device mode of Google Chrome, I get the following error:

`md-grid-list: md-cols attribute was not found, or contained a non-numeric value`

And, it infinitely sends requests to the node server.

I tried to google it out, but not enough help is available. Any help on this forum would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error tells you that you are missing `md-cols` for the breakpoint that fits your chosen device.

If you look at the layout breakpoint introduction [here](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/layout/introduction) and the  grid-list demo [here](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/gridList), you will find out, that you are missing the `md-cols-xs="1"` attribute. `sm` is not the smallest breakpoint.